# Converting varchar values to decimal while handling NULLs and EMPTY strings as 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-convert

I have a column of varchar datatype populated with a mix of values such as 1.2, 5.33 while also having NULLs and EMPTY strings.
I want to convert all the values to decimal while treating NULLs and EMPTY strings as 0.

I can change the NULLs or EMPTY strings using the CONVERT function like below. Like this I replace the NULLs and EMPTY strings with a varhcar 0.

```
CASE WHEN Column1 = '' OR Column1= NULL THEN '0' ELSE Column1 END AS 'NewColumn1'
```

However what I want to do is to be able to then convert this data (output of NewColumn1) into decimal but when I place the CASE statement into a CONVERT or a CAST function I will have errors.

I also tried the following.
C`ONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), ISNULL(Column1, '0'))` however it fails since here I am not handling the EMPTY strings.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem.

Comment: `... OR Column1 IS NULL ...`

Comment: `CAST((CASE WHEN Column1='' OR Column1 IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Column1 END ) AS DECIMAL(18,2))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple way:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 4), ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1, ''), '0'))
```

Your `CASE` statement doesn't work because you're cheking if `Column1 = NULL`. You sholud check if it `IS NULL`.

```
CASE WHEN Column1 = '' OR Column1 IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Column1 END AS 'NewColumn1'
```

Comment: Thank you Marko. This first solution is working and also very clean.

Comment: @user2307236 if this answer solved your issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour), it is not sufficient to say thanks. Also When having many well answered question without accepting good answers. Other user will not pay attention for your questions. good luck

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(Column1, ''),0) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) FROM table
```

Comment: This doesn't work as required - it doesn't work for empty string.

Comment: I fixed that issue

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(Column1, ''),'0') AS DECIMAL(14,5)) AS Column1 
FROM table
```